# MySQL hierarchy - only show children that are not parents

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I have a table of categories.

Ex (modified from http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
|          11 | MINI                 |      7 |
|          12 | OFFERS               |   NULL |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Entries that do not have a parent are root nodes.  I would like to make a view that shows the root nodes and their descendents.

Ex:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| category_id | category_total                                           |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|           3 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > Tube                         |
|           4 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > LCD                          |
|           5 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > Plasma                       |
|           8 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > MP3 players > Flash |
|          11 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > MP3 players > Mini  |
|           9 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > CD Players          |
|          10 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > 2 way radios        |
|          12 | OFFERS                                                   |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

If for instance category 5, 'Plasma' should get a child category, 'Plasma' should not turn up as a final category in this list, but it's descendents should instead:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| category_id | category_total                                           |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|           3 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > Tube                         |
|           4 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > LCD                          |
|          13 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > Plasma > Small               |
|          14 | ELECTRONICS > Televisions > Plasma > Big                 |
|           8 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > MP3 players > Flash |
|          11 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > MP3 players > Mini  |
|           9 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > CD Players          |
|          10 | ELECTRONICS > Portable electronics > 2 way radios        |
|          12 | OFFERS                                                   |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

There will be maximum 4 levels of categories.

Comment: Either with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()`, or a `LEFT JOIN` & `WHERE IS NULL` on a non-nullable column should get you the endnodes, getting the trail to them is in the link you provided.

Comment: Hillyer doesn't cover this?

Answer (score 0):

try this query ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4edd/1/0))

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT c.category_id,
       IF(p3.name IS NULL,
          IF(p2.name IS NULL,IF(p1.name IS NULL,c.name,CONCAT(p1.name,' > ',c.name)),
             CONCAT(p2.name,' > ',p1.name,' > ',c.name)),
          CONCAT(p3.name,' > ',p2.name,' > ',p1.name,' > ',c.name)
          )
       as category_total

FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category child ON child.parent = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN category p1 ON p1.category_id = c.parent
LEFT JOIN category p2 ON p2.category_id = p1.parent
LEFT JOIN category p3 ON p3.category_id = p2.parent
WHERE child.category_id is null;
```